# Repository URLs broken in Gitea after restoring a backup

Tags: gitea

I have restored a Gitea backup. Everything seems to be fine except that clicking on URLs in the WebUI opens a URL only containing the hostname or a wrong URL (it is missing the repository part of the URL).

If I create a new repository, I can access it as usual when clicking the URL. If I manually type the URL of repositories (e.g. gitea.my-domain.de/username/reponame.git) I can access it.

My first attempt was setting a ROOT_URL in app.ini, but this did not work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This just happened to me and it looks to be because in the `gitea` database the `owner_name` column from the `repository` table gets dumped as `NULL`. Interestingly the `owner_id` column keeps the correct value.

I am using mysql(mariadb) and did the following:

```
USE gitea;
SELECT id, name, owner_id, owner_name FROM repository;
```

Inspect this output just to make sure it looks sane.

```
UPDATE repository INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.id = repository.owner_id SET owner_name = `user`.name;
```

This will lookup and replace the user_name based on the user_id from the user table.

```
SELECT id, name, owner_id, owner_name FROM repository;
```

Just to make sure it worked. Compare the first output to the second.

I checked for issues on the gitea repo of github and didn't see any matching these symptoms. I will open a issue there later and link this article.

Comment: Tested successfully when migrated from 1.11.0 on Windows to 1.13.0 on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and managed to solve it with the help of the previous answer by [a7hybnj2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14129068/a7hybnj2).

My instance is running with an SQLite database, for which the update command needs to look like this:

```
UPDATE repository
SET owner_name = (SELECT name
          FROM `user`
          WHERE (repository.owner_id = `user`.id))
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM `user`
          WHERE (repository.owner_id = `user`.id));
```

The modification is necessary as SQLite syntax does not supporting `INNER JOIN` within an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Remember to save the SQLite database before closing then run `sudo service gitea restart` to restart the Gitea service for your changes to take affect.